# Sorting a list of dictionaries in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a list of dictionaries. My goal is to sort dictionaries with multiple (possibly the same) keys in the same way, even if the dictionaries are in a different order or if the keys are in the dictionary in a different order.

In Python 2, I have used the following:

```
a = [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 3: 4}, {5: 6}]
b = [{3: 4, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 1: 2}, {5: 6}]
a.sort()
b.sort()
a
Out[20]: [{5: 6}, {1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}]
b
Out[21]: [{5: 6}, {1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}]
```

This succeeds in my goal of creating two sorted dictionaries that look exactly the same.

I am trying to do the same thing in Python 3, where .sort() does not work for a list of dictionaries.

I have tried different ways.

1.

```
sorted(a, key=lambda d: max(d.keys()))
```

This does not work:

```
a = [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}, {5: 6}]
b = [{3: 4, 7: 8}, {1: 2, 7: 8}, {5: 6}]
a2 = sorted(a, key=lambda d: max(d.keys()))
b2 = sorted(b, key=lambda d: max(d.keys()))
a2
Out[1]: [{5: 6}, {1: 2, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 3: 4}]
b2
Out[2]: [{5: 6}, {3: 4, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 1: 2}]
```

2.

```
a2 = sorted([list(zip(x.keys(),x.values())) for x in a])
a3 = [{k: v for (k,v) in x} for x in a2]
```

This does not work:

```
a = [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 3: 4}, {5: 6}]
b = [{3: 4, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 1: 2}, {5: 6}]
a2 = sorted([list(zip(x.keys(),x.values())) for x in a])
a3 = [{k: v for (k,v) in x} for x in a2]
b2 = sorted([list(zip(x.keys(),x.values())) for x in b])
b3 = [{k: v for (k,v) in x} for x in b2]
a3
Out[1]: [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {5: 6}, {7: 8, 3: 4}]
b3
Out[2]: [{3: 4, 7: 8}, {5: 6}, {7: 8, 1: 2}]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the Python 2 result in Python 3??

Comment: In python2, almost any object can be compared, meaning anything can be sorted. In your case, the sorting is completely arbitrary. In python3, the objects in question must be compatible. If not, you'll need to provide a sorting key.

Comment: Do you want to sort the dictionaries based on the number of key:value pairs held in each or sort by a list of sorted keys or even something else. Once you've established how you want the sort to proceed, you then can write the appropriate sorting code.

Comment: I think the key _to your question_ is to understand exactly how do you want the lists to be sorted. Saying _"My goal is to sort dictionaries with multiple keys **in the same way**"_ is not enough. Also, you cannot sort dictionaries themselves - what you see is a random order of items. You example works for your particular set of keys and values but will produce "unsorted" dictionaries for other values.

Comment: My goal is simply to sort them in the same way indeed. I would like to make sure it can be sorted the same way for ANY combination of keys and values. The only preference on how the sorting itself happens, is how long is takes. I want it flexible (so can handle any keys and values) and fast.

Comment: I have managed to write several pieces of code that can do what I want, but it all takes long. The function I use the sorting in takes 2.5 seconds when looping over 8000 entries using .sort, but I have only managed to do it in ~60 seconds while writing my own functions for it. That is the main reason I am looking for a one-liner, like has mostly been suggested here already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use all items of each dict while sorting, and `d.items()` iterates items in arbitrary order, so they need to be sorted. And this is your sorting key:

```
a = [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 3: 4}, {5: 6}]
b = [{3: 4, 7: 8}, {7: 8, 1: 2}, {5: 6}]
sorted(a, key=lambda d: sorted(d.items()))
Out: [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}, {5: 6}]

sorted(b, key=lambda d: sorted(d.items()))
Out: [{1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}, {5: 6}]

x = [{1: 2},{1: 3}]
y = [{1: 3},{1: 2}]
sorted(x, key=lambda d: sorted(d.items()))
Out: [{1: 2}, {1: 3}]

sorted(y, key=lambda d: sorted(d.items()))
Out: [{1: 2}, {1: 3}]
```

Note that `sorted(a, key=...)` creates a new list, while `a.sort(key=...)` makes sorting in place.

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly, thanks a lot!! Same results that the .sort gave me, just as fast (even a tiny bit faster) and it works perfectly in both Python 2 and 3. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Just once more explaining to people why this solves my problem and ikkuh's solution does not: Pavlo's solution also consistently sorts between two dictionaries that have the same keys but different values.

Comment: can someone explain me how this sorting is working here?

Answer (score 4):

Sorting on all `keys` in the dictionaries can be done with:

```
a.sort(key=lambda d: d.keys())
b.sort(key=lambda d: d.keys())
```

To get the result you want we need to sort the keys on ascending order as follows:

```
a.sort(key=lambda d: sorted(list(d.keys()), reverse=True))
b.sort(key=lambda d: sorted(list(d.keys()), reverse=True))
```

This gives the following result:

```
>>> a
[{5: 6}, {1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}]
>>> b
[{5: 6}, {1: 2, 7: 8}, {3: 4, 7: 8}]
```

Edit: In order to sort based on the values as well (asked in the comments) the following might work:

```
a.sort(key=lambda d: sorted(list(d.keys()) + sorted(list(d.values())), reverse=True))
b.sort(key=lambda d: sorted(list(d.keys()) + sorted(list(d.values())), reverse=True))
```

Comment: (So I understand that my question does not fully cover this scenario, but) This solution does not work when there are 2 dictionaries with the same key, but different values. If you have a = [{1: 2},{1: 3}] and b = [{1: 3},{1: 2}] it keeps these two lists in their original order instead of what Python 2 .sort does (which is making both lists [{1: 2},{1: 3}])